# How to switch from one control to another using the tabulator key in controlP5 from processing?

Tags: processing, control-p5

I am doing a GUI on processing and using controlP5. I would like to use my keyboard to switch between controls but I failed miserably.

Another thing I would like to do is remove the cursor from the TextAreas since always is a character behind instead of beeing at the end.

Have someone a clue of how to achive that? I would be really happy if someone with bigger knowledge knows how to, I am really getting monkey!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did figure it out in my own. These ControlP5 are not really intuitive controls. There is not documentation at all, and the most common features in controls like this one (usability) are not covered in the examples. A pity. Anyways, here it is:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

boolean isTabPressed = false;

void keyPressed()
{
      if(keyCode== TAB){
          isTabPressed = !isTabPressed;

         if(isTabPressed){
           Textfield tf = (Textfield) cp5.getController("textValue");
           tf.setFocus(true);
           Textfield tf1 = (Textfield) cp5.getController("textValue1");
           tf1.setFocus(false);
          }else{   
           Textfield tf = (Textfield) cp5.getController("textValue");
           tf.setFocus(false);
           Textfield tf1 = (Textfield) cp5.getController("textValue1");
           tf1.setFocus(true);
         }
     }
            
}

void setup()
{
    size(400,180);
    
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

    cp5.addTextfield("textValue")
     .setPosition(100, 30)
     .setSize(200, 20)
     .setAutoClear(false)
     ;
     
    cp5.addTextfield("textValue1")
     .setPosition(100, 90)
     .setSize(200, 20)
     .setAutoClear(false)
     ;
     

}

void draw()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution! ControlP5 is not as documented than some other projects like it, but the various class it uses are documented ([Textarea](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/Textarea.html) for an example), and [you can also read the source code](https://github.com/sojamo/controlp5) (which is priceless for a programmer, as documentation can easily be out-of-date but source code don't lie - I've helped several people with ControlP5 just because I can read it). Were you also able to fix the cursor issue?

Comment: Hi Laancelot, thanks for your reply. I did not solve  the cursor issue yet. I think that can be a font issue, I will try to check it today. Respect to the switching of controls I just realice that it can just be done with the TextFields and not with the Buttons, and thats a pity. Or you think that is possible? thanks!

Comment: I think you are right with the font, as I ran your code and it looked fine on my end. Yesterday I read the source code to see if you had missed something about a tab index, and found that the control deliberately ignore the tab key. I though about modifying the class to make up for it, but since we have to instantiate it through the ControlP5 class it meant having to deal with way more code than I wanted to. On the bright side, if somebody does it, the ControlP5 class owns all controls so it's really easy to jump from a control to another one once the index is established.

Comment: About the cursor again, I believe that you may make it invisible by changing it's color for the control's background color. You can change the control's background color with `.setColorBackground(color(0,0,255))` and the cursor color with `.setColorCursor(color(0,0,255))` (I used a random color, don't overthink it).

Comment: I just re-read your last comment, do you mean that you would like to have a list of ordered controls which lets you jump to one another with the tab key (including buttons, textfields, and others if you want to) ?? I think it very possible, but I'd have to check later.

Comment: Hi Lancelot, yes. I want to switch to a button too, but I dont think it is possible

Comment: I solved the problem with the cursor. Now is in place, if you use the next: .setDecimalPrecision(x) in a textfield the cursor is not working properly anymore